# Why is there no current over resistor next to node?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[n00b alert]

I'm wondering why there's no current across the 4-ohm resistor.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: I'm wondering what's connected to A and B .

Comment: Current goes through a resistor, voltage appears across it.

Comment: Does this make anyone cringe :O? Best to study electronic circuitry from the basics. And I'm right now a bit sceptical as to how the 10V battery only has a load of 5Ω which allows a dangerous amount of current, thus creating some significant heat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of A and B as having a resistor of infinite resistance between them.  That's one way of defining an open circuit. As a result, the current in the loop containing the infinite resistance is zero. Current will only flow in a closed loop, at least at this level of analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The node A is not connected to anything. It's left open. Imagine a wire hanging loosely. It will not conduct any current. With resistor or otherwise.